# Should I expect that mailx would work with SLURM?

Tags: email, job-scheduling, mailx, slurm

This simple script (`simple_mail.sbatch`) will send two mails if run directly from the command line. It runs fine on the head node and any of the cluster nodes I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Getting ready to send an e-mail from $HOSTNAME"

# Try using a pipe
echo 'Testing pipe version' | mailx -s 'testing mail app' user@example.com

# Try using a heredoc
mailx -s 'testing mail app' user@example.com << 'END'
Testing < version
END

echo "Finished on $HOSTNAME"
```

However, when run using `sbatch`, I see the results of the first and last echo commands in the captured standard output, but no e-mail is sent.

```
sbatch simple_mail.sbatch
```

A "wrapped" command and `srun` don't fair any better:

```
sbatch --wrap='echo "Testing" | mailx -s "testing mail app" user@example.com'

srun ./simple_mail.sbatch
```

---

Version info:

```
slurm 14.11.8
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
Heirloom mailx 12.5
```

By the way, `mailx` may be called as `mail` on some systems.

---

I've looked at other [slurm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508040/use-bash-variable-within-slurm-sbatch-script) and [mailx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176531/mailx-does-not-work-with-subprocess) questions on stackoverflow, but none seemed to address this problem.

I've looked at environment variables and have even tried setting all of the environment variables to be the same (even those starting with SLURM) but the difference in behavior still remains.

Comment: Can you send mails from the compute nodes where the jobs run?

Comment: Yes. I can send mails as long as I run the command directly instead of using `sbatch` or `srun`. Thanks for asking. I've updated my question as a result.

Comment: watch the `MAILRC` variable

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Thanks! It didn't seem to make a difference in our case, but I incorporated it into the question in case it helps someone else. In the end, we tried out `mutt`, which does work with SLURM on our system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer, but it works: Try [`mutt`](http://www.mutt.org) instead.

After spending too much time trying to get `mailx` to work, we tried `mutt` and it does the job. After `mutt` was installed and confirmed to work, I tried `mailx` again (as a sanity check), but it still does not work when run by the SLURM scheduler.